# How To Add My Own Svg Image Just Like Logo Is Shown By Default In Create-React-App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I've got a clean create-react-app install and I wanted to add my own svg image to show, the same way that logo is shown i.e.:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';

{logo}
```

However when I import my own svg the same way as logo is imported and try to use it, it prints a url like this on the screen:

```
 /static/media/menu.92677579.svg
```

instead or rendering the image, could someone help me figure this out please?

Comment: could you show how you are importing ?

Comment: exactly the same way as the logo one: import menu from './menu.svg';

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you write `{logo}` you're just embedding a URL.
If you want to show an image, use the `<img>` tag like the default template [does](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/bee4ecec8679f472ee81bcfdcd2861d28f55f30b/packages/react-scripts/template/src/App.js#L10).

```
<img src={logo} alt="My logo" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if I'd prefer the `<svg>` tag in my document instead of the `<img>` tag? or is that no recommended?

Comment: Indeed it's better a inline svg, I'd like to know how to add inline svgs (the svg tag) with create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './logo.svg';
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Logo is an actual React component */}
      <Logo />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is a new special syntax when importing SVG in React. The ReactComponent import name is special and tells Create React App that you want a React component that renders an SVG, rather than its filename. You can read more about it here, but keep in mind that this is a React library special syntax:

Reference link: [Create React App](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files)

Comment: Please don't use images of code, but put the code directly in the answer, so it can be copied later on. Just style it with the {} button...

Answer (score -2):

I found I could pass in the logo image file (.svg) as a prop from the component "calling ClsSplash".  The import in the calling component sent a reference to some sort of optimized svg file at */static/media/logo.5d5d9eef.svg*   I have no idea where that is or why it is necessary.  In any case, I see an animation working referring to that prop.

My ClsSplash is the guts of the default APP.tsx you get when you make a new project with

**npx create-react-app hello-world --typescript**

I set up another JSX image tag to see how to import the svg file directly within the ClsSpash component.  This is works for me running (F5) a "project" within VS2019 launched with IISExpress into Google Chrome 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as logo from './../../logo.svg'; 
/* imported item has to have the same name as the file name (without extension) */
/* fyi article explains the optimized svg */
/* https://react.christmas/2018/18 to handle a Data URL */

import '../../fldrAppearance/fldrCSS/App.css'; /* for div classname attributes */


class ClsSplash extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props: any)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    public componentDidMount()
    {
        // console.log("logoPath is " + logo);
    }

    public render()
    {
        const lclLogo = logo;
        console.log("prop logoPath is " + this.props.svg);

        return (
            <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                    {/*}<img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" /> {*/}
                    <img src={`${lclLogo}`} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <img src={`${this.props.svg}`} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                <p>
                    Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
                    </p>
                <a
                    className="App-link"
                    href="https://reactjs.org"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                    Learn React
                    </a>
            </header >
            </div>
            )
    }

}

export default ClsSplash;
```

[screenshot of two spinning logo svg images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFTr3.png)

Comment: There's so many things wrong with this code: first of all you don't need to `import * as` for files, webpack and babel should know how to handle this (if they don't you configured your application wrong or you're using an old version of Typescript). You also don't need to `{\`${file}\`}` for the img srcs, it's redundant just write `{file}`.